# Rebinning pandas dataframe with datetime and categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains two columns:

```
column1   column2   
C1        date1       
C1        date2
C3        date3
C2        date4
C2        date5
...       ...
```

The first columns represents a category (C1, C2, C3), the second a date in format YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS. I need to group the data in a time series containing bins of equal duration (say 1 week) and the number of occurrences of each category. The purpose is to display three curves with the number of monthly occurrences of each category. I have transformed the column2 into a datetime index with:

```
df['column2']= pd.to_datetime(df['column2'])
df = df.sort_values(by='column2',ascending=True)
```

I know that  pd.groupby(['category']) can give me the sum or the counts of each category, but then I lose the date information. How can I achieve my purpose?

**Edit 1**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random 
import time

def random_date(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    d = random.randint(1, int(time.time()))
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category', 'date'])
for i in range(100):
    date = random_date(i)
    category = random.randint(0,2)
    d = {'category': category, 'date': date}
    df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)

df = df.set_index(['date'])                                                               
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)                                             
df = df.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True)
```

This is where I am stuck. I want now to be able to plot three time series with a time bin of, say, 1 week and the number of occurrences of each category.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? I think expected output from sample data, not `date1` by like `2020-01-01`.

Comment: I've added my code, where I use a random sample of dates and category to give you an idea of what the dataset looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with column name and get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last if need categories in columns add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'), 'category']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```